# Why does JSF hit xhtml page 3 times

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF application. Upon hitting an entry point.

```
/MyApp/start.xhtml
```

The page contains a view action which will decide from the query string params which page to go to.

```
<f:viewAction action="#{startController.newQuote()}" />
```

.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class StartController {
public String newQuote(){
    ....
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nav.performNavigation("aboutYou.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

The `aboutYou.xhtml` is reportedly hit 3 times according to my filter.

```
@WebFilter("*.xhtml")
public class TrackingFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TrackingFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        LOG.trace("request URI: " + req.getRequestURI());
}
```

why is this? I suspect it is to do with the PRG pattern used by `?faces-redirect=true` but I might expect to see this 2 times, not 3.

how do I optimise my filter so that I only catch a single action of moving to that page?

Comment: The way how you're handling navigation is unnecessarily clumsy (there's no means of a POST request here and it can just return a string outcome like a command button action), but it shouldn't cause 3 requests on the target page. To exclude one and other, what exactly does the browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor say? (don't forget to set it to preserve the log on redirects)

Comment: Firebug's console with persist turned on shows x2 HTTP200 POSTs

Comment: how do you mean clumsy? can you suggest a cleaner way to have an inbound link that processes the entry and redirects to a page according to the queryString params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment:

> *The browser shows x2 HTTP200 POSTs*

That's thus 1 GET request as fully expected. Those POST requests can happen if you're firing some ajax request on load of the requested page. E.g., assuming PrimeFaces, with `<p:outputPanel deferred="true">`, `<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true">`, etc. Usually all related to lazy loading.

You can in the filter recognize POST requests by inspecting `HttpServletRequest#getMethod()`.

```
if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {
    // It's a POST request.
}
```

Or, specifically JSF ajax requests by inspecting `Faces-Request` header.

```
if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
    // It's a JSF ajax request.
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're not performing a PRG here at all. The `<f:viewAction>` is by default only invoked on a GET request, not on a POST request (it only does that when you add `onPostback="true"`). And, the `<f:viewAction action>` behaves exactly the same as `<h:commandButton action>`, including returning a navigation case outcome as usual (with the only difference that it's a GET, not a POST). So all that navigation handler and redirect mess is unnecessary.

```
public String newQuote() {
    // ...

    return "aboutYou.xhtml";
}
```

The navigation handler approach is only necessary if returning a `String` outcome is not supported (like in `<f:event type="preRenderView">`). The redirect is only necessary if the initial request is a POST request (like in `<h:commandButton action>` or `<f:viewAction onPostback="true">`).

Comment: You are correct. I have a primefaces <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true">. Removing this results in only 2 hits. I will try out your other advice now. Thank you very much.